# C++ Relational Data Structure Library

Tags: library, c++, in-memory-database

I have some live data that does not fit well into the object oriented paradigm. I am looking for a library in C++ that can store, index, and query this data with a relational database interface at runtime.

I do not want to interface with this library using `std::string` typed queries, much less SQL queries. Ideally the interface would be something closer to relational algebra, like `relation_a * relation_b` would be the cross product of two relations.

Comment: Is it ok for you to spawn additional processes? Use the disk? What hardware? What OS? What license? What price? etc.

Comment: I would like free, same process, preferably OS-independent, entirely in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think boost::multi_index was what I was looking for.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html#rationale

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for - since it is SQLish, but [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) seems to have an in-process-memory mode, if I read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). Most in-memory DBs, however, live in separate processes rather than in a library.